# Scala's '::' operator, how does it work?

Tags: list, scala, operator-keyword

In Scala, I can make a caseclass, `case class Foo(x:Int)`, and then put it in a list like so:

```
List(Foo(42))
```

Now, nothing strange here. The following is strange to me. The operator `::` is a function on a list, right? With any function with one argument in Scala, I can call it with infix notation.
An example is `1 + 2` is a function `(+)` on the object `Int`. The class `Foo` I just defined does not have the `::` operator, so how is the following possible?

```
Foo(40) :: List(Foo(2))
```

In Scala 2.8 RC1, I get the following output from the interactive prompt:

```
scala> case class Foo(x:Int)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo(40) :: List(Foo(2))
res2: List[Foo] = List(Foo(40), Foo(2))
```

I can go on and use it, but what is the explanation?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

From the Spec:

> 6.12.3 InfixOperations An infix operator can be an arbitrary
>   identifier. Infix operators have
>   precedence and associativity defined
>   as follows.
>
> ...
>
> The associativity of an operator is
>   determined by the operator’s last
>   character. Operators ending in a colon
>   ‘:’ are right-associative. All other
>   operators are left- associative.

You can always see how these rules are applied in Scala by printing the program after it has been through the 'typer' phase of the compiler:

```
scala -Xprint:typer -e "1 :: Nil"

val r: List[Int] = {
  <synthetic> val x$1: Int = 1;
  immutable.this.Nil.::[Int](x$1)
};
```

Comment: It also applies for passing type parameters to type constructors. Let say you have a case class ::[H, T](head : H, tail : T); and class SomeType[A]; then you could do both new SomeType[::[String, Int]]("a", 3) and new SomeType[H :: T]("a", 3)

Answer (score 24):

It ends with a `:`. And that is the sign, that this function is defined in the class to the right (in `List` class here).

So, it's `List(Foo(2)).::(Foo(40))`, not `Foo(40).::(List(Foo(2)))` in your example.

Comment: In other words, `a ::::: b` (just to be silly) is the same as `b.:::::(a)`. Additionally, methods whose names end in colon and used in infix style associate to the right, rather than to the left, so `a :: b :: c` is the same as `c.::(b.::(a)))`

Answer (score 21):

One aspect missing in the answers given is that to support `::` in pattern matching expressions:

```
List(1,2) match {
  case x :: xs => println(x + " " + xs)
  case _ => println("")
}
```

[A class :: is defined](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/trunk/src///library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala) :

```
final case class ::[B](private var hd: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B])
```

so `case ::(x,xs)` would produce the same result. The expression `case x :: xs` works because the default extractor `::` is defined for the case class and it can be used infix.

Answer (score 20):

> The class `Foo` I just defined does not
>   have the `::` operator, so how is the
>   following possible:
>
> `Foo(40) :: List(Foo(2))`

If the method name ends with a colon (`:`) the method is invoked on the *right operand*, which is the case here. If the method name doesn't end with colon, the method is invoked on the left operand. For example, `a + b`, `+` is invoked on `a`.

So, in your example, `::` is a method on its right operand, which is a `List`.