# Scala confusing compile time error while working with List of Tuples

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am working through [Ninety-Nine Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) to learn more Scala. I am on P12 and coded the below solution for the problem.

```
def decode(l : List[Tuple2[Int,Symbol]]) : List[Symbol] 
            = l foldLeft(List[Symbol]()) { (symbols:List[Symbol], e:Tuple2[Int, Symbol]) => symbols ::: List(e._2) }
```

And I am getting the below compiler error.

```
 error: type mismatch;
 found   : (List[Symbol], (Int, Symbol)) => List[Symbol]
 required: Int
                        = l foldLeft(List[Symbol]()) { (symbols:List[Symbol], e:
Tuple2[Int, Symbol]) => symbols ::: List(e._2) }
```

What is causing the compiler error?

Scala version: Scala code runner version 2.10.0-M3 -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like it's your use of the infix foldLeft call, you just need to change it to:

```
def decode(l : List[Tuple2[Int,Symbol]]) : List[Symbol] 
        = l.foldLeft(List[Symbol]()) { (symbols:List[Symbol], e:Tuple2[Int, Symbol]) => symbols ::: List(e._2) }
```

Note the "l.foldLeft" rather than "l foldLeft", I suspect the compiler can't quite determine what is a parameter to what.

Comment: Thanks Sean for the answer.Are there there any good docs, links, blog posts, etc about this?

Comment: There are some entries on here already around some of this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592642/when-to-use-parenthesis-in-scala-infix-notation
I'd say a rule of thumb would be to only do it when there's a clear reason to (like in the "4 + 4" case).

Answer (score 3):

The solution is already given but I think there is a need for more explanation:

You are only allowed to leave parentheses and the dot if your expression is in operator position. An expression is in operator position if it has the form `<object> <method> <param>`. This is not the case with methods which contain multiple explicit parameter lists as `foldLeft`. Thus you have to write `<list>.foldLeft(<init>)(<function>)`. Nevertheless Scala has a special rule to work around this - you can insert another set of parentheses: `(<list> foldLeft <init>) (<function>)`. Furthermore there is another method called `/:` which is a synonym to `foldLeft`, defined as `def /:[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B = foldLeft(z)(op)`. It allows you to write `(<init> /: <list>) (<function>)`. Maybe you just noticed here that the symbols between the first parentheses are swapped - this is because of the rule that each method ending with a colon is right- instead of left-associative ([further explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827293/scala-operator-how-it-works)).

Now I want to give you some hints for further refactorings:

- `Tuple2[A, B]` can be written as `(A, B)`
- You don't have to write all the types. Some of them can - and should - be left to clear up your code (I know you are a beginner and want to write this. Only as a hint...). But don't leave
- Lists are mostly named something like `xs` or `ys` because this means "lots of x" or "lots of y". This is not very important but common
- You can patter match on parameters to extract them to easy to read names: `... { case (a, (b,c)) => ...}`
- Your code does not work as it claims the task. You need something like `List.fill(<n>)(<elem>)`
- Don't append elements to a list, this is `O(n)`. `:::` implicitly is a append operation - look at the [sources](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L107).
- For this task `foldLeft` is not be best solution to come up with. `foldRight` or the synonym `:\` may be more efficient because the `:::` operation requires less elements to copy. But I prefer `flatMap` (see below), which is a `map+flatten`

  - You can use a for-comprehension to solve this, which often will be easy to read. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1059501/465304) for more information how for-comprehensions are realized internally.

All in all the example solutions:

```
object Test extends App {
  def decode1(l: List[Tuple2[Int, Symbol]]): List[Symbol] =
    l.foldLeft(List[Symbol]()) { (symbols: List[Symbol], e: Tuple2[Int, Symbol]) => symbols ::: List.fill(e._1)(e._2) }

  def decode2(xs: List[(Int, Symbol)]): List[Symbol] =
    (xs foldLeft List.empty[Symbol]) { case (xs, (n, s)) => xs ::: List.fill(n)(s) }

  def decode3(xs: List[(Int, Symbol)]): List[Symbol] =
    (xs foldRight List.empty[Symbol]) { case ((n, s), xs) => List.fill(n)(s) ::: xs }

  def decode4(xs: List[(Int, Symbol)]): List[Symbol] =
    (List.empty[Symbol] /: xs) { case (xs, (n, s)) => xs ::: List.fill(n)(s) }

  def decode5(xs: List[(Int, Symbol)]): List[Symbol] =
    xs flatMap { case (n, s) => List.fill(n)(s) }

  def decode6(xs: List[(Int, Symbol)]): List[Symbol] =
    for {
      (n, s) <- xs
      ys <- List.fill(n)(s)
    } yield ys

  val xs = List((4, 'a), (1, 'b), (2, 'c), (2, 'a), (1, 'd), (4, 'e))
  val ys = List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e)

  println("start testing")

  val tests = List[List[(Int, Symbol)] => List[Symbol]](decode1, decode2, decode3, decode4, decode5, decode6)

  for (t <- tests)
    assert(t(xs) == ys)

  println("finished")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the explanation.Also, appreciated your valuable hints and tips :)

Answer (score 1):

If you make the call to `foldLeft` explicit by using `l.foldLeft`, then the error disappears:

```
def decode(l: List[Tuple2[Int,Symbol]]): List[Symbol] =
  l.foldLeft(List[Symbol]()){(symbols:List[Symbol], e:Tuple2[Int, Symbol]) =>
      symbols ::: List(e._2)}
```

Have a look at the first answer of to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181533/what-are-the-precise-rules-for-when-you-can-omit-parenthesis-dots-braces-f) for a very detailed explanation of Scala's call syntax that also covers your case.