# Why (copy) appending to Seq in Scala is defined as :+ and not just + as in Set and Map?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Scala's Map and Set define a `+` operator that returns a copy of the data structure with a single element appended to it. The equivalent operator for `Seq` is denoted `:+`.

Is there any reason for this inconsistency?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Map and Set has no concept of prepending (`+:`) or appending (`:+`), since they are not ordered. To specify which one (appending or prepending) you use, `:` was added.

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3):+4
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> 1+:Seq(2,3,4)
res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Don't get confused by the order of arguments, in scala if method ends with : [it get's applied in reverse order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827293/scala-operator-how-it-works) (not a.method(b) but b.method(a))

Answer (score 20):

FYI, the accepted answer is not at all the reason.  This is the reason.

```
% scala27
Welcome to Scala version 2.7.7.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_06).

scala> Set(1, 2, 3) + " is the answer"
res0: java.lang.String = Set(1, 2, 3) is the answer

scala> List(1, 2, 3) + " is the answer"
warning: there were deprecation warnings; re-run with -deprecation for details
res1: List[Any] = List(1, 2, 3,  is the answer)
```

Never underestimate how long are the tendrils of something like any2stringadd.

Comment: To be more clear, this is due to List being covariant, but Set being invariant, and that is the bigger problem, in my view, than any2stringadd.