# Operand order in Scala List.prepend (::)

Tags: list, scala, operators

Odersky has brilliantly optimized Java syntax, enabling object calls without dots and parenthesis. I.e. instead of `list.prepend(item)`, you now simply write `list :: item`, which also turns language operators into simple object methods. Here, List defines `::` (prepend) operator. However, you normally write it vice-verse in Scala, using `item :: list`. It suggests that every (listable) type defines the `::(List)` operator, which is unbelievable. How is the operand reversal implemented? I cannot figure it out from the source code

```
class List[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A]
  def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] =
    new scala.collection.immutable.::(x, this)
```

It seems that ::(val head, val tail) also stands for a type name. But it does not fit the `head :: tail` pattern anyway.

Comment: `::` is Scala's "cons", the non-empty list and counterpart to `Nil`. Note that you can also use infix notation for binary type constructors - think of a generic type as a "type function" which produces a resultant type: `type \/[+A, +B] = Either[A, B]` then `def foo: String \/ Int = ???`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any operator with a `:` on its right side has its operands flipped. There's other operators that make use of this too (can't think of any examples off the top of my head though).

Comment: With your info, I have found [a similar question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2827570/4550451). Thanks.

Comment: @RecognizeEvilasWaste Np. It's nice thinking about Scala. I miss it :/