# Scala: Undocumented Extractor `::`

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Using the [api documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current) of Scala it is obvious how Lists are constructed using the `::` Syntax, which refers to a method on Lists.

But the extractor in infix notation for pattern matching as in `{ case 1 :: 2 :: _ => ??? }` would require an object with an unapply method.
So my question is: Where does this undocumented extractor `::` come from in Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how `::` implementation looks like

```
/** A non empty list characterized by a head and a tail.
 *  @param head the first element of the list
 *  @param tl   the list containing the remaining elements of this list after the first one.
 *  @tparam B   the type of the list elements.
 *  @author  Martin Odersky
 *  @version 1.0, 15/07/2003
 *  @since   2.8
 */
@SerialVersionUID(509929039250432923L) // value computed by serialver for 2.11.2, annotation added in 2.11.4
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
  override def tail : List[B] = tl
  override def isEmpty: Boolean = false
}
```

For more info visit [Scala's '::' operator, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827293/scalas-operator-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Thank you. This is correct and my assumption was not: This code is also [documented](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html). I initially thought, every case class would have a corresponding object generated, but this is probably an implementation detail.

Comment: Yes, There is extractor generated for `case class` by default.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of `::` on Lists, the extractor is generated as part of the [`case class ::`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/$colon$colon.html).
Usage of `::` in pattern matching is referred to as constructor pattern.