# Why does the `is not a member of` error come while creating a list in scala using the :: operator

Tags: scala

I am learning scala and I've noticed that the following line of code doesn't work

```
     val worldFreq = ("India", 1) :: ("US", 2) :: ("Berlin", 10)
```

Results in the error : `error: value :: is not a member of (String, Int) val worldFreq = ("India", 1) :: ("US", 2) :: ("Berlin", 10)`

However this line of code works perfectly

```
val worldFreq = ("India", 1) :: ("US", 2) :: ("Berlin", 10) :: Nil
worldFreq: List[(String, Int)] = List((India,1), (US,2), (Berlin,10))
```

Can someone help me understand the error message and the fact the it works with Nil.

Comment: ("India", 1) :: ("US", 2) :: ("Berlin", 10)::Nil do this it will work you are using :: operator on a tuple which is not the member of a tuple you can use it on List

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala's '::' operator, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827293/scalas-operator-how-does-it-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because `::` is right-associative operator.

So, when you type `(1, 2) :: Nil` it transforms to `Nil.::((1,2))`. And obviously, there is no `::` method on tuples, so you can't write `(1, 2) :: (3, 4)`.

You can read more here: [Scala's '::' operator, how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827293/scalas-operator-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Thanks @yevhenii. Also helpful to mention that Nil is an empty list which is quite different from null.